# What is different between return 1 and return 0? And how backtracking work in given code?

Tags: c, function, boolean, return, backtracking

```
int solve(int a[])  
{      
    int index,i;    
    index=find_index(a);

    if(index==101)
    {
      return 1;
    }

    if(index!=101)
    {
      for(i=1;i<=9;i++)
      {
          if(cheak_coll(a,i,index)==1 && cheak_grid(a,i,index)==1 && cheak_row(a,i,index)==1)
          {
            a[index]=i;

            if(solve(a))
            {
                return 1;
            }

            a[index]=0;
          }
      }
   }
   else 
   {
        return 1;
   }

  return 0;
}
```

In given example what is different between `return 1` and `return 0`?

I used `int fun()` in place `bool fun()`. In bool function return true and return false are same as `return 1` and `return 0`?

And how backtracking work in this code?

Comment: `solve` what? This is a given example of what?

Comment: @YuHao: Sudoku, of course. The word "backtracking" is a dead giveaway.

Comment: You have the code, so only you can say, what it is actually doing. You should try doing step-by-step debugging of the code and the mystery will unwrap itself.

Comment: Returning 1 from `solve` will make the `if( solve(a) )` evaluate to `true` and returning 0 will make it `false`. This is all one can tell you by the snippet you have provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In given example what is different between return 1 and return 0?

Judging by the following block code

```
if(solve(a))
{
    return 1;
}
```

it seems that a return value of `0` indicates not solved yet and a return value `1` indicates solved.

> I us `int fun()` in place `bool fun()`. In bool function `return true` and `return false` are same as `return 1` and `return 0`?

Yes.

> And how backtracking work in this code?

I don't know.

The function is a bit sloppy. You have the block:

```
if(index==101)
{
  return 1;
}
```

If `index` is equal to `101`, the function will return. If it is not, it will go to the next statement. Hence the statement:

```
if ( index != 101 )
```

is redundant. The corresponding `else` will never be exercised since the function would have already returned `if ( index == 101 )`.

The function can be simplified to:

```
int solve(int a[])  
{      
   int index,i;    
   index=find_index(a);

   if(index==101)
   {
      return 1;
   }

   for(i=1;i<=9;i++)
   {
      if(cheak_coll(a,i,index)==1 && cheak_grid(a,i,index)==1 && cheak_row(a,i,index)==1)
      {
         a[index]=i;
         if(solve(a))
         {
            return 1;
         }
         a[index]=0;
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

I hope the simplified version makes it easier for you to figure out how the backtracking works for your problem.